# Input does not behave like expected, java FileReader

Tags: java, filereader

I have the following code which when executed should get an input integer from the specified file and output the multiplication table up to 10 with the number given.

Right now I do not know why but when reading the number it converts it to something totally different.

Input was 3 and the file recognized num as 51.

Any good guesses what is going on and I am not seeing?

```
public class exercise2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("e://ex2.txt");
            int num = reader.read();
            for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
                System.out.println(num + " * " + i+ "= "+ num*i);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()

> Reads a single character.

So, this method simply returns the first character of your file (cast to an `int`).

What you want is to use a `Scanner` since you want to *parse* the file:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("e://ex2.txt"));

int input = s.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Reader.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read()) reads a single character.

The character `3` has the Unicode codepoint 51 (decimal).